# How do I add an existing class to a DLL produced by CodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource?

Tags: c#, compileassemblyfromsource

I am creating a dll using codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource, and passing in my code as a string.

I want the resultant dll to include another class that is already in my code and doesn't change.

ie, instead of this line:

```
compiledResults = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,myCode);
```

I want something lie this:

```
compiledResults = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,myCode, typeof(anotherClass));
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why are you trying to add an already defined type?  Maybe you can go with a different option.  Like an IOC controller or maybe even load the assembly into the current AppDomain directly from what is using your compliedResults.

Comment: I want to create a single dll rather than 2. Will try your other suggestions too, thanks